# Is it a good idea to store chat records in MongoDB's collection?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am writing a chat software with ChatGPT, and I want to save the user's chat records with ChatGPT to the MongoDB collection. I need 2 functions to:

- List the `id`, `createTime`, and `cost` of all chat records for a certain user, excluding content.
- View chat records based on the user's `uid` and `id`.

I don't know if it's reasonable:

```json
{
    "uid": "xxxx1",
    "history": [
        {
            "createTime": "xxxxxx",
            "cost": 1000,
            "data": [
                {
                    "role": "ai",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "role": "ai",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "createTime": "xxxxxx",
            "cost": 1000,
            "data": [
                {
                    "role": "ai",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "role": "ai",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB database would be a good fit.
Instead of storing data in the normal collection, I would suggest to been through time-series collection. as this use case would be more efficient for storing data on a time basis, and above chatbot store time too, so time-series indexing, querying would be more efficient for your use case.

create time series collection:

```
db.createCollection("sampleTimeSeries", {
  timeseries: {
    timeField: "history.createTime", // Use the timestamp field path
    metaField: "uid"                 // Optional field for metadata
  }
})
```

how collection json looks

```
{
    "uid": "xxxx1",
    "history": [
        {
            "createTime": "xxxxxx",
            "cost": 1000,
            "data": [
                {
                    "role": "ai",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                // ...
            ]
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Insertion of element :

```
db.sampleTimeSeries.insertOne({
    "uid": "xxxx1",
    "history": [
        {
            "createTime": "xxxxxx",
            "cost": 1000,
            "data": [
                {
                    "role": "ai",
                    "msg": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                // ...
            ]
        },
        // ...
    ]
})
```

Comment: I think time-series collections are better suited for regular data (e.g. data from a sensor coming every second) but not for chat data where the times are random.